# P30N06 Mosfet Not Working Correctly

Tags: led, mosfet, led-strip, motion

I have an N Channel Mosfets I'm trying to use as a switch for a motion sensor and an LED strip light (12V <0.8A). It seems like no matter how I hook up the mosfet it is always set to 12V or stuck at 6.5V. It's my first time using one, so I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Mosfet: RFP30N06LE
Motion Sensor: SR501 (Signal is ~3.3V)

[image]

Comment: What voltage do you apply at the gate? What’s the recommended/specified Vgs at the load you intend to use in the transistor? EDIT: looked up the transistor. Seems well suited for 3.3 V operation. Can you please measure it just to be sure?

Comment: @winny Oops sorry about that. It's a 12V source and I measure 3.2-3.4V at the gate.

Comment: Does your 12 V source drop under load by any chance? Can you please draw a schematic (built in tool here, press edit and click on the schematic symbol) instead of a wiring diagram and post a photo of your setup. Something is fishy here

Comment: After playing around with the cricut some more I think the issue is the gate voltage. The motion sensor puts out 3.3v. When I use the 12v source and ground as the gate it seems to operate as it should. Does anyone know of a different model mosfet that would be able to operate off of 3.3v reliably?

Comment: Plenty of them! You can search by Vgsth on Digi-Key. Also, you can consider a NPN instead if you have some mA worth of gate drive current to spare. You will need to add a base resistor though but it you can operate down to 0.7 V.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm on the right track; both the s8050 and BC547 NPN transistors would be fully activated at 3.3v to act as a switch for the lights right? I cant find any specs on how many amps the SR501 can send through signal.

Comment: BC547 can only do 100 mA, so it’s too weak for you. Most likley yes, but if you need to buy a transistor anyway, there should be hundreds if not thousands available with <3.3 V Vgsth and ample current capacity at almost no cost.

Comment: I appreciate you helping me out with all this!... So based on what I've learned so far a mosfet like the DMN1019USN should work for the above application? It has a Vgs(th) of 0.8V, fully powered on at 2.5V, and can handle 9.7A. Only confusion is the Vgs (Max) being +-8V. Would this still work?

Comment: Almost. It has only 12 V Vds breakdown, so not enough for your application. I would not dare to use less than a 20 V rated one.

Answer (score 0):

The gate and source form a capacitor, whose capacitance must be overcome in order for the drain/source to begin to conduct. In order to this, you can place a resistor (Something between 400-1000 Ohms should suffice) between the gate and the source. Be careful to not allow the voltage to exceed Vgs in the datasheet.

Comment: What are you on about? Why would a resistor across gate-source change anything? How would 3.3 V go over the 10 V specified in the datasheet?